# Google Sheets Script Looping through a list of sheet names located in cells

Tags: google-sheets

I cobbled together and modified the below script which emails the contents of a Google sheet to an email address listed within the same sheet. It runs fine but is limited to the sheet I list by name.

What I can't seem to work out is looping it so that the sheet name (currently hard coded as "NYC") is pulled from a list of sheet names located within the spreadsheet.  I'd like it to run the script referencing the sheet name listed in A1, then if A2 if one is listed, then A3 if one is listed etc etc.

Is this possible?

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('NYC');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var recipient = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue(); // "TO" email address
  var subject = "Inbound Shipments Scheduled for Delivery On " + Utilities.formatDate(
                  sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(),
                  ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
                  "MM/dd/yy");
  var schedRange = sheet.getRange("A3:Q102");
  // var schedRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())


  // Put Name & Date into email first.
  // We only want the schedule within borders, so
  // these are handled separately.
  var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
  body += '<H1>'+ 'Shipments Due ' +'</H1>';
  body += '<H2>'
        + Utilities.formatDate(
            sheet.getRange("B2").getValue(),
            ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
            "EEEEE, MMMMM d, yyyy")
        + '</H2>';
  body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
  body += '</div>';
  debugger;

  // recipient = '*********@gmail.com';  // For debugging, send only to self
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code from the definition of getRowsData() down in the sample of the [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merg](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge)e tutorial.  This will allow you to read the contents of sheet once, which will speed up your code.  You can then loop through the data and use column Headers to check for values.  Your code would change quite a bit, to something like:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    function sendAllEmails() {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrimaryDataSHEETname");
      var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("A1:Z")
      var myRows = getRowData(sheet, sheetRange);

      for (var i=0; i < myRows.length; ++i){
        if(typeof(myRows[i].Sheet1) !== 'undefined'){ 
           sendIndividualEmail(myRows[i].Sheet1);
      }

        if(typeof(myRows[i].Sheet2) !== 'undefined'){ 
           sendIndividualEmail(myRows[i].Sheet2);
      }
    }

    function sendIndividualEmail(sheetName) {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      //Grab necessary data from tehis sheet and send emails

    }
```

You could pass additional information from the first sheet to the function for creating the email, such as recipient, subject, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm don't think I understand how this works.  In the original one above, and some additional functions it does grab the tables and email them pretty well, but I can't get it to loop through a series of sheets, which are named in a column within the spreadsheet, but on another tab. Is that possible?

Comment: To better answer this I would need to see your sheet. It can be a copy with sample data.  Basically my first function would read the column of sheet names, loop through it, and run the second function for each one.  I am using the retRowData() function from the linked tutorial to only call the google servers once in the first function and once for each iteration of the second function.  I then loop through the data saved in memory instead of making multiple calls to the file.  This will speed things up quite a bit.  Each time you use .getValue() you are making a call to the servers.

Comment: I've made a copy.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ebLcPO9GaxI2kl5Yi_pkafB4Iyu5FH9ZafANLUuxY-Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChrisMcNutt See my code in the KS Copy Email NYC script file inside your sample file.

Comment: I think I see what you are doing there.  I'm getting errors when running it though.  Trying to debug.

Comment: This has all been amazing so far, thank you so much for the help!  "TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null. (line 28, file "Email_NYC")"  I think that is indicating it's assigned a null value to the sheet name so it errors out.  I see the code that is checking for the length of the column, but it might be tossing back a false length since that column is driven by a query formula.  is there another way to check for blank cells in that column and end the script?  I have copied the script into "New Emails"

Comment: Did you copy the code in getRowsData.gs?  I put the pertinent code from the Simple Mail Merge tutorial there.

Comment: yeah, i still get the errors.  Should I put that code into the same file as the other fuctions or should they be seperate?

Comment: Ahh,  Sorry, misread that.  Change the line   `var range = sheet.getDataRange();`  to   `var range = sheet.getRange();`  The method does not contain 'Data' in its name.  I made changes to the sendEmail function as well, such as passing the sheet name.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it another try.  Right now, the original one, once I added some of your other functions is working except for a persistent error i hit when it runs out of sheets to call on...  though it still works....  Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I updated my code to test for blank values for the sheet names and skip any which are blank.